# Move task from Gulp 3.9 to 4 +

Tags: async-await, gulp, task, gulp-4

I have updated Gulp from 3.9 to 4. I'm not able to run the task. Below is the code before and after migration

Before:

```
gulp.task('default', [
    'html',
    'assets',
    'javascript',
    'outside-scripts',
    'css',
    'libs',
    'watch'
]);
```

After:

```
gulp.task('default', function (cb) {
    gulp.series(
        'html',
        'assets',
        'javascript',
        'outside-scripts',
        'css',
        'libs',
        'watch'
    );
cb();
})
```

I am not sure what is the problem in the syntax I am using, but the task just starts and ends with no errors either. Probably the series is not being called. Can anyone help me with the syntax please.

Comment: you can import from gulp like this
const { src, dest, task, watch, series, parallel } = gulp;
and use function like this

task('default', series(
        'html',
        'assets',
        'javascript',
        'outside-scripts',
        'css',
        'libs',
        'watch'
    )
);